# WSO2 taking too much time to respond on token expiry

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 api manager when a token has expired, it takes too much time to respond with `401 unauthorized` error code.

I modified my curl request and added the `--no-buffer` tag and then I see the response comes however the curl connection is still kept open.

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Do you see any error logs in the console?

Comment: Can you confirm that the invoking with a valid non-cached token does not take a similar amount of time?

Comment: No error...from the curl request I see it fails saying  transfer closed with 814 bytes remaining to read...looks like this is caused because of chunked response which is enabled by default in wso2 but not sure